# Where do I post useful HOWTOs for different topics?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have read the question and answers of this question ([Is it useful to post questions I already know the answer to on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28289/is-it-useful-to-post-questions-i-already-know-the-answer-to-on-stack-overflow)), and the general consensus is to provide the answer after a few days for people to answer (I think...).

However, I have battled through some problems in Ubuntu 11.04, Vim, Ruby on Rails, Win7, etc, and I wanted to share those with the community and help other beginners not to fall in the same problems.

Do I post these here as they are setup questions? Do I post them on Stack Overflow? Do I post each in its relevant site (in which case what do I do whith win7)? I thought about a blog or a site, but that would not get a good readership.

I'm new to these sites as well so I apologise for any breach of etiquette.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you phrase your howto in the form of a question, and on the correct site, I think it would be ok. Something like "How do I configure Ubuntu 11.04 to do **X**" where **X** is something quite tricky and would not easily be found in Google already. Then post the solution as an **answer**.

There's no point doing a "Windows 7 step-by-step install" quesion as that is already covered on many many internet sites and really doesn't fit the SE[OUF] Q&A format. Bear also in mind that you may get answers as well from the community that may be a *better* explanation than yours, and you could also mark your answer "community wiki" to allow others to easily edit it and contribute improvements.

You could also post them to a blog, then post answer snippets in the answer with a link to the blog (with a full disclosure that you run the blog, that is).

Comment: Don't community wiki the *question* (regular users can't do that anyway), but you might mark the *answer* as community wiki so that other users can add to it.

Comment: Outsourcing information is normally not the way to go.

Comment: Thank you all!! It's what I was looking for.